# continuous chain of ones or zeros for transmit

Tags: digital-communications

If my data has long chain of 1's or 0's. Can the data be modulated and transmitted as it is. Will this have any effect of  the receiver adc as this may increase dc value of the signal or any other block in the receiver chain?
should the data be scrambled?

Answer (score 1):

A dominant concern with long runs of ones or zeros is the ability of the receiver to establish symbol timing. The receiver clock is independent from the transmitter clock, so without transitions in the data the receiver will not be able to determine the clock used in the transmitter for each symbol, and will ultimately drift off. Whitening the data has other benefits for equalization and overall efficiency.

Comment: Thanks . I agree with you. but as it increases DC value does it effect ADC output if i am sending a zero IF signal to ADC?

Comment: In practical realizations there will always be DC offsets due to any imbalances in the receiver. Usually DC is ignored for this reason as there is no easy way to distinguish it (This is one reason why the DC bin is nulled in OFDM receivers). The answer to your question is yes the data should be scrambled.

Comment: @ Dan sorry to bother u again . U mean to say the reason it should be scrambled is for timing related issued but not due to dc offset on adc? Thanks again

Comment: @Steve Both reasons. The ADC will have DC offset with or without your data and often that will be AC coupled to the receiver. Long runs will make timing acquisition difficult.

Comment: @ so irrespective of the type of the data the dc offset is present in ADC. so even the scrambled data will have the dc offset? so scrambling might not help here? probably i should take into consideration in digital domain. what i mean is does the continuous o's or 1's and random data with behave the same way with respect to adc? i.e. no drop in signal after adc if continuous 0's or 1's are present?

Comment: Is your ADC DC coupled? What does 0 or 1 map to at the ADC input in terms of voltage level? For example is 1 a positive voltage and 0 a negative voltage? (or what)? The ADC if DC coupled will have a DC offset that would need to be nulled in order to recognize your waveform competing with this offset. Scrambling will avoid this since you won't require DC coupling to decode what data was transmitted.